# GCP functions can't call each other

Tags: python, http, google-cloud-platform

I can't get GCP function to be authenticated to send requests to other functions. I do have service key for runtime service account. Here's the code I use. I'm getting 401

```
  service_account_key = json.loads(creds)
  creds = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_key, target_audience=url
  )
  request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
  creds.refresh(request=request)
  token = creds.token

  r = authed_session.post(
    url=url,
    json=data,
    headers={
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': f'bearer {token}'
    }
  )

  print(r.text)
```

Comment: If you are inside a Cloud Function, why are you using a service account key, when you can start your Cloud Function with a specific service account (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#individual) ? And for your authorization issue, make sure the caller has the role `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` on the target CF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in a cloud functions, you shouldn't (mustn't) use a service account key file. Indeed, you can customize the [Cloud Functions service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity), and then get the credential from the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata)

The, for a [service to service call](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#python). The link points to Cloud Run service but the underlying infrastructure is the same and the Cloud RUn documentation better. You need an id_token to be able to call your Cloud Functions.

In addition, to authorize as cloudfunctions.invoker the requester service account.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me get it properly (no service account key) and find the real problem - my request was send to http instead of https.